# userInteraction is enabled but button action isn't called

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am new to iOS programming. My cell is in a .nib. This cell displays an image which is working fine. I don't want the cell to perform any action or be selected. So, I have the following code :

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
cell.contentView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

My problem is I have a button which isn't called on touch. I have an action defined in the cell.m file. But nothing happens. I also tried adding the button programmatically, but in vain. I will appreciate any help or pointers as I have tried this for past few hours. I am pretty sure I am doing something silly.

Update:

This is how my cell xib structure looks - 
[image]

There cell.nib, cell.m and cell.h. There is MainViewController which uses dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier method to get the cell. This works fine as I am able to see the cell with the correct image. Action method is defined inside cell.m
[image]

Here is the xib file
https://www.dropbox.com/s/mzqzi6iz8lkbx2f/SHTableCell.xib

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post some of the code for the cell class? I am able to add a button with an action to a UITableViewCell that has SelectionStyleNone and it works as expected.

Comment: you're surely missing something. anyways... how have you added the button to the cell? where is it's target-action method located?

Comment: @staticVoidMan I have tried adding the button via IBuilder and also have done it programatically. Both don't seem to work. Target action method is defined in cell.m

Comment: My guess would be that either 1) your outlets are connected incorrect so I would check the inspector or 2) Something is blocking the touch input to the button.

Comment: share only your `cell.xib` file via dropbox or similar. it'll be the quickest way to identify the problem.

Comment: @staticVoidMan uploaded the file

Comment: the `Test Cell` itself doesn't have a checkmark for `User Interaction Enabled` ... also, your re-use identifier is not set

Comment: The .m and .h file don't have much code apart from the one pasted here and one for setting the image. I am not sure what is re-use identifier and how can I set it

Comment: well... you **should** set a re-use identifier. ...How're you even getting by without that? anyways... what's in your `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: in cellForRowAtIndexPath I just use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier and return cell based on some condition. I have registered nib in viewDidLoad. Thank you for your input, this is my observation - now  I have enabled userInteraction for cell and if I define my button programatically when the cell is created and set  my action method in the view controller which implements UITableViewDelegate then it gets called.

Comment: @Sandbox : great, so i'll take it that your problem is now fixed. anyways... the string that you pass during `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` should be the re-use identifier that you should specify in the `xib` (however... since you've registered the cell nib in your viewDidLoad, it isn't crashing but I'd still advise you to specify this re-use identifier string via your xib)

Comment: @staticVoidMan thank you for your help. I will later investigate what was wrong with using IB for creating the button. If you put this as answer, I will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking the `SHTableCell.xib` you shared, it seems you have prevented user interaction on the cell itself so enabling user interaction on it's `contentView` / `subView`s will not make a difference.

In your xib, select "`Test Cell`" and check "`User Interaction Enabled`"

---

Also, it seems you haven't specified a **re-use identifier** to the cell.
It would be better if you specified one so that your `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` could properly re-use the cell.

So... if you have something like:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//...
    SHTableCell *cell = (SHTableCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SomeIdentifier"];
//...
}
```

then, "`SomeIdentifier`" is what should be in the xib in the first place.

Comment: For others who face such issue - also remember to look at didSelectRowAtIndexPath and willSelectRowAtIndexPath